# I want when the user doesn't give any input this program will give 1's multiplication as output

Tags: python

```
def multiplication_maker(m=1):
    n = 1
    while n < 11:
        print(m,"*",n,"=",m*n)
        n += 1

x = input("Enter the multiplication you want =" )
x = int(x)

multiplication_maker(x)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example case, in plain English ?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the length by using `len()` then assigning 1 to it

```py
def multiplication_maker(m=1):
    n = 1
    while n < 11:
        print(m,"*",n,"=",m*n)
        n += 1

x = input("Enter the multiplication you want =" )
if len(x) == 0:
    x = 1
x = int(x)

multiplication_maker(x)
```

Comment: Or perhaps `x = int(x) if x else 1`. However, this (and your code) **assume** `x` is a digit, and will fail otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution

You can use the fact that an empty string is evaluated as false and set a condition

```
x = input("Enter the multiplication you want =")
if not x:
    x = "1"
x = int(x)
multiplication_maker(x)
```

#### Smart

Using the fact that is a the left operand is false (ie empty string) then the right operand will be evaluated and returned you can do that trick

```
x = int(input("Enter the multiplication you want =") or "1")
multiplication_maker(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def multiplication_maker(m=None):
    try:
        m = int(m)
    except:
        m = 1
    n = 1
    while n < 11:
        print(m, "*", n, "=", m * n)
        n += 1

x = input("Enter the multiplication you want =")
multiplication_maker(x)
```